# How can I be 100% sure the electric power is cut to my cooker?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I need to change a radiant ring on my electric cooker. Please explain exactly (to a novice) how to cut the power to the unit. Do I need to turn ALL the fuses off at the main (old style) fuse box or just remove the 30 amp cooker one. Would do I harm by turning  off the fuse box completely whilst working on cooker??

Comment: Photos are always useful

Comment: Please revise to tell us more about your appliance. Is it hard-wired? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: If you do pull multiple fuses, take a picture of the fuse box before you start, so you know which ones go where. Some fuse types can be swapped between circuits, and you want to make sure the proper fuse amperages go back to where they belong.

Comment: Along with what @user71659 said about pics, I'd make sure to label the fuses/breakers, too. You don't want to accidentally swap them, only for a unreliable breaker to make it seem like something on a different circuit has failed. If you keep them in the same spots, you'll know if the cooker repair "doesn't work" you can try a new breaker/fuse to see if that was the real problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "electric cooker"?

Comment: @HotLicks Did you [check a dictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cooker#Noun)?

Comment: @user71659 -- To most folks in the US an "electric cooker" would be a Crock Pot or some such -- ceramic bowl with a gallon or so capacity and a built-in electric heater.  You set it on the kitchen counter and plug it into the wall outlet.

Comment: Here in North America we’d just unplug it from the wall (a big 220V plug used for stoves and electric dryers etc.).

Answer (score 18):

It is fine to turn off your entire house's electrical supply if that makes you feel better. But do be aware that the fridge and freezer won't keep things cold forever without power, though a few hours will be fine, especially if you leave them closed.

With a non-contact tester the typical operation is to

- first check that the circuit is live.
- then turn off the circuit
- then check the circuit is dead
- then check that the tester still works on another circuit that is still live

Comment: The fridge and freezer should be good for  4 or 5 hours without power with the doors kept close.  Should be long enough to change a radiant ring.

Comment: OTOH, there is nothing wrong with turning off _just_ the circuit on which you're working. Turning _everything_ off may give a psychological benefit, but it provides no real tangible, physical benefit.

Comment: I'd caution that it may not be "fine" to turn off the whole house: you're working in low light conditions, which is less safe than full light conditions.

Comment: Older homes with descent amount of electrical DIY artifacts are better turned off altogether. Using a battery-powered light and setting a clock or two is way better than touching something that becomes unexpectedly live. Guess where I know from... and I live in a 230V country.